# Removing values from set based on a function

Tags: java, set

I have a `LinkedHashSet` of "vectors".

Some of the vectors in the set may be "greater" than others. (vectors are 8-dimensional and each entry is non-negative)
Oversimplified: if I have `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` and `[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0]` in the set, then `[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` is greater than `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` and so I wish to remove `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

The actual comparison is not directly based on numerical values since not all entries are compared using the same criteria, see examples below.
I have a method on my "vector" objects such that if I call `v1.isGreaterThan(v2)` it will return true for when `v1` is greater than `v2` (for the example above `[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].isGreaterThan([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) == true`).

The current implementation of doing this check is horribly slow `O(n^3*m)` (see comment below):

```
List<V> lst = new ArrayList<>(linkedHashSet);

for (int i = lst.size()-1; i >=0; i--) {
    V vI = lst.get(i);
    for (int j = 0; j <i; j++) {
        V vJ = lst.get(j);
        if (vI.isGreaterThan(vJ)) {
            vI.setValueTo(vJ);
            lst.remove(j);
            linkedHashSet.remove(vJ);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

`linkedHashSet.size()` gets to be in the 10,000s or even 100,000s, so I desperately need to speed that up.

What can I do?

EDIT: Changed to show more dimensions.

---

## EDIT: Further Examples

`[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].isGreaterThan([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) == true`

`[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].isGreaterThan([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) == false` <- 1st index is greater but second is not.

`[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].isGreaterThan([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) == false` <- still false

Some of the other entries are compared differently. But all of this is handled by `.isGreaterThan()`.

Comment: Your question is unclear. For example, assuming that all vectors can be compared to all others, that means your endresult is __just a single vector__ (after all, only one can be the greatest and all others therefore have another element that is greater and should be removed!). Is that what you actually wanted? If it is not what you wanted, describe how 2 vectors can be unrelational (neither is greater than the other), what does that look like.

Comment: If truly [A] all vectors are either 100% identical or one is 'greater', and [B] you want to find the greatest, this can be done in O(n*m), n being the size of your list of vectors and m being the average size of any given vector. That's considerably better than the O(n^3*m) that your code is now (you forgot about the 'm' factor, and `lst.remove(j)` is contributing another (relatively fast) `O(n)` to it all, unfortunately), so your judgement that your current take is really slow is indeed correct and can't be fixed with tricks due to algorithmic complexity.

Comment: @rzwitserloot. I updated the complexity, thanks for the comment!

As for a single vector, no you will not. I perhaps did not explain it well below, see the update. [1, 1] is greater than [1, 0], but [0, 1] is *not* greater than [1, 0] (not would [0, 2] be greater than [1, 0]).

Comment: Can two differently composed vectors be considered equal.  E.g. `[1,-1]` and `[1,1]`  The sums of squares would be the same if that is part of your criteria.  It might help if you shared the details of your Comparator.

Comment: @WJS each entry is non-negative. There are more criteria for comparing them. But does the inner workings of `isGreaterThan` make a difference for this?

Comment: First, to start you put them in a set for some reason.  Why would you do that? 
 And what is your `equals` method to allow the `Set` to do its thing and remove duplicates?  Also, please look at your code.  It is full of syntax errors and would not be able to compile.  Just paste your existing code into the question.

Comment: @WJS. Sorry about the syntax, it's been fixed. The actual code is essentially identical minus the change of function names to make more sense outside of the context of the whole program.

The `Set` is needed since the items being stored are procedurally generated to generate all possible permutations of several pieces of input. Storing in a List would impose severe penalties on deduplication.

The `equals` evaluates one component at a time. I.e. v1[0] == v2[0], v1[1]==v2[0]. (shown using array index syntax)

Comment: Okay.  But assuming that you are comparing all values to each other using the same criteria, wouldn't you end up with `one` greatest value or a `list of n equal` values that are the greatest?  An actual example of before and after with explanation would really help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246251/discussion-between-user9985-and-wjs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about sorting the vectors? Then you just iterate over them, and at some point you know that everything that comes next will be smaller.

Then you can achieve nlogn complexity.

Comment: I am currently attempting that, I need to convert `isGreaterThan` from returning a bool to the different ints required for a Comperator.

Comment: This would have been the way to go. Ultimately the Comperator proved too tricky to implement. I managed to optimize other parts of the code so that the poor O(n^2) scaling of the naive approach would only become an issue in extreme situation.

Comment: Can't you reuse `isGreaterThan`? i.e. `if (v1.isGreaterThan(v2)) 1 else if (v1 == v2) 0 else -1`